# Dell WD19TB and ElementaryOS

Tags: display, plank

I have a Dell wd19TB thunderbolt dock and it seems to work fine with ElementaryOS until I try to disable the Laptop display and only use my external displays. I am trying to disable the laptop display however it wont disable. I tried this same functionality on Ubuntu and it worked with no issues. I also made sure the "bolt" application was installed in ElementaryOS. My laptop is a Lenovo yoga 720. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in terminal command:

```
xrandr -q
```

to shows the exact names of displays

This one shows VGA (15-pin blue connector), HDMI, Display Port and LVDS (laptop screen):

```
xrandr -q | grep 'VGA\|HDMI\|DP\|LVDS'
```

This is a sample command to turn off LVDS-1 and enable VGA-1:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off --output VGA-1 --auto
```

To switch back:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --off --output LVDS-1 --auto
```

You must combine and replace VGA-1 with the output name for your external screen. I hope I explained it enough clear.